# Best way to move entire directory tree in PHP

Tags: php, copy, directory, file-rename

I would like to move a file from one directory to another. However, the trick is, I want to move file with entire path to it.

Say I have file at

```
/my/current/directory/file.jpg
```

and I would like to move it to

```
/newfolder/my/current/directory/file.jpg
```

So as you can see I want to retain the relative path so in the future I can move it back to `/my/current/directory/` if I so require. One more thing is that `/newfolder` is empty - I can copy anything in there so there is no pre-made structure (another file may be copied to `/newfolder/my/another/folder/anotherfile.gif`. Ideally I would like to be able to create a method that will do the magic when I pass original path to file to it. Destination is always the same - `/newfolder/...`

Comment: is it okay to execute system commands, or you want to do it in php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try something like this if you're in an unix/linux environment :

```
$original_file = '/my/current/directory/file.jpg';
$new_file = "/newfolder{$original_file}";

// create new diretory stricture (note the "-p" option of mkdir)
$new_dir = dirname($new_file);
if (!is_dir($new_dir)) {
    $command = 'mkdir -p ' . escapeshellarg($new_dir);
    exec($command);
}

echo rename($original_file, $new_file) ? 'success' : 'failed';
```

Comment: This was my idea initially - I just missed existence of dirname() and it seemed a bit cumbersome. Other than that it works like a charm. Why -1?

Comment: Because I wrote move() instead of rename(), I updated of course !

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use the following

```
<?php 
$output = `mv "/my/current/directory/file.jpg" "/newfolder/my/current/directory/file.jpg"`; 
if ($output == 0) { 
   echo "success"; 
} else { 
   echo "fail"; 
} 
?>
```

please note I'm using backtick ` to execute instead of using function like exec

Comment: `echo ($output) ? 'fail' : 'success';` ;)

Comment: Sorry but in my test, if target Directory does not exist it does not copy the file.